# Does Samba 4.7.6 running on Ubuntu 18.04 support the storing of a Windows encrypted file or folder without losing encryption?

Tags: server, windows, samba, encryption

I have a single text file on my Windows 10 Desktop that I've encrypted using the Windows "Files->Properties->General->Advanced "Encrypt contents to secure data." When I try to save this to my share on my Ubuntu 18.04/Samba 4.7.6 Server, Windows returns: "Do you want to copy this file without encryption?
You are copying the file to a destination that does not support encryption." Of course, I can say "copy without encryption," and it copies to the server without a problem--except the file is no longer encrypted.

I used to get a Windows 10 error message similar to this when I copied Windows files that had more than one data stream, and I added the line "**vfs objects = streams_xattr**" to the smb.conf file under the share that I'm using--and copying Windows files with more than one data stream now works perfectly fine.

So my question is this: Does Samba 4.7.6 support copying intact a single Windows encrypted file to the server such that it retains its Windows encryption? Is there a line I need to add to the smb.conf file that would enable this capability? Maybe this is not possible as I haven't been able to find anything on it. My Ubuntu server runs EXT4 disks and runs as a standalone server with a workgroup defined. BTW: I have multiple users with individual permissions to shares and they all have been working for the last two years.

So, to be clear, I'm not interested in whether my data travels from Windows to the server in an encrypted format (though it probably does), nor do I want to encrypt any of the server disks. All I want to do is be able to copy a Windows encrypted file or folder with files to the Ubuntu/Samba server and retain Windows encryption "property." --Same as copying Windows files with multiple data streams and preserving them.

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Files encrypted on Windows are not easily portable in most cases, so the answer is “no”. If you wish to store files encrypted on Windows to an external device then you’ll need to use a different encryption tool.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. It confirms that I'm not missing anything. I appreciate it.